# Expected value of a function of an exponential random variable

Tags: expected-value, exponential-distribution, nonlinear

I want to find the expected value of a non-decreasing cost function $c$ of an exponentially distributed random variable $X$ with mean $a$. Considering some constant $t$, the expected value that I would like to find is:

$E[ c(t+X)]$.

If this setting is too general, I would consider making additional assumptions on the cost function $c$ in order to get an exact expected value.

Of course, I know that for a linear or a piecewise constant function $c$, this is easy. However, this is a strong assumption, which I rather don't want to make.

Comment: The [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) tells us that $$E[c(t+X)] = \int_0^\infty c(t+x)\cdot \frac{1}{a}e^{-x/a}\,\mathrm dx.$$ Can you calculate the value of this integral for the given function $c(\cdot)$? If it is an increasing function and the growth is too rapid, the integral might diverge....

Comment: Thank you for this answer. In my case, the cost function $c$ has a fixed upper bound, so it will not diverge.

Comment: Then I don't understand what the issue is. If you have a formula for $c(x)$ -- maybe even a multiple-line formula such as $c(x)=x^2$ for $0<x<1$ and $c(x) = 1$ for $x \geq 1$ -- then you should be able to compute $E[c(t+X)]$ exactly. If you know $c(x)$ only as a set of points $(x_i, c(x_i))$ and know only that it is nondecreasing, then you should be able to get an approximation and bounds on $E[c(t+X)]$. To get an _exact_ value is not possible unless you wish to make additional assumptions, and then the value is dependent on what additional assumptions you choose to make.

Comment: This is no longer an issue for me, since applying LOTUS does the job indeed. Thanks again.